# Querying a custom element, is returned as UnknownElement

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer, dart-polymer

I've defined a custom element, `chat-view` and have it displaying on a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
     <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="chat_view.html">
  </head>

  <body>   
    <chat-view id="chat">
    </chat-view>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I then query for the chat-view:

```
final ChatView chatView = query("#chat");
```

The previous line causes the following exception:

```
Exception: type 'UnknownElement' is not a subtype of type 'ChatView' of 'chatView'.
```

Is there a way to query for my custom element in such a way that I get an object of ChatView, instead of UnknownElement?

Comment: In JS there's a "WebComponentsReady" event that fires http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#WebComponentsReady. Not sure what the Dart port has. You won't be able to query the DOM until the elements have been upgraded and ready to go, so waiting for this event is recommended before doing immediate work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I found that the custom element instance is accessed through the UnknownElement's `xtag` property.

`final ChatView chatView = query("#chat").xtag;`